# Could not find module "ember-data/index"

Tags: ember.js

i got an error when running a project in emberJs

Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-data/index` imported from `ember-data/initializers/ember-data`
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-cli-app-version/initializer-factory` imported from `hqapp/initializers/app-version

please anyone knows

Comment: Update ember-data module to the latest version

Comment: please show your `package.json` and `bower.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below

1) bower install --save ember#2.0.0

2) bower install --save ember-data#2.0.0-beta.1

It solves the issue.......:)

Comment: ember and ember-data is served from NPM from ember-cli 2.11 onwards

Answer (score 0):

From ember-cli 2.11 version onwards `ember` and `ember-data` and all of ember internal dependencies are served from NPM. so you don't need to install it through `bower`.

So I would encourage you to update `ember-cli` to latest version always(2.13.3).
For your specific issue updating the `ember-data` to 2.14.3 might fix it. and also consider upgrading addon to the latest version.